# What kind of arguments does this function take?

Tags: javascript

```
function countChars(elm) {  
    if (elm.nodeType == 3) { // TEXT_NODE  
        return elm.nodeValue.length;  
    }  
    var count = 0;  
    for (var i = 0, child; child = elm.childNodes[i]; i++) {  
        count += countChars(child);  
    }  
    return count;  
}
```

I tried passing this function a string like `countChars("hello")`; but that didn't work.  What are examples of elements that I can pass?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It expects a reference to a DOM node. That could be a text node (`nodeType == 3`) or an element node (`nodeType == 1`) by the look of the function. For example:

```
countChars(document.getElementById("someId"));
```

The following HTML would cause the above call to return `5`:

```
<span id="someId">Hello</span>
```

If the argument is a text node the function returns the number of characters that make up that node. If the argument is an element node the function recursively counts the number of characters that make up the descendant text nodes of the element.

The following HTML would cause the above call to return `10` (the child node is included):

```
<div id="someId">Outer<span>inner</span></div>
```

You can see the full list of [node types on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType).

Comment: +1 for distinguishing a general *DOM node* from the specific *element node*.

Comment: +1 for being most accurate and explanatory within that 1 minute. :-)

Answer (score 3):

It expects DOM nodes, like something you'd get from `document.getElementById()` or the list of child nodes on another DOM node.

What it does is find all the text nodes in the list of child nodes of an element and count up how many characters they contain.  It does it recursively, so it will find *all* the text within a container, no matter how far separated in the element graph.

Also it should be noted that this code expects a node to be either a text node or else an element. There are other types of nodes, however, most notably comment nodes.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you should pass a dom element.

Answer (score 2):

An element (node, actually, hence why it checks if nodeType is a text node), e.g.:

```
countChars(document.getElementById("myid"));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get nodeType over a DOM fragment, so... you must enter a DOM element as input

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nodeType

The example from that link shows it

```
var node = document.documentElement.firstChild;
if(node.nodeType != Node.COMMENT_NODE)
  alert("You should comment your code well!");
```

Comment: Remember that IE doesn't support the node type constants. And I'm not sure what relevance comment nodes have to this question.

Comment: Relevant as the way to figure out what to put as parameter for that function is precisely the nodeType attribute. Mainly because OP was not curious enough to look at that. So the COMMENT_NODE is just an example here, is a constant as YOU say. The deep idea is "check examples!"

Comment: I was just pointing out the fact that the function in question will throw an error if you pass a comment node into it, so it's probably not the best example to use! And it won't work in Internet Explorer!

Comment: Yes, I completely agree with you that it does not work in IE. But I was just saying that the documentation from MDC shows 'that' example. And it helps on getting the idea... but yes, perhaps something with a wider scope could help even more